use universal property of localization to show that $R_f\cong R[x]/(fx-1)$
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $D=\{\,f^n\,|\,n\geq0\,\}$ be the multiplicative set where $f\in R$ is not nilpotent. And the question is the topic. The following is my idea:
Let $\varphi:R[x]\to D^{-1}R$ defined by $r\mapsto r$ and $x\mapsto1/f$. Then clearly $\varphi$ is surjective so that
$$
R[x]/\ker\pi\cong D^{-1}R
$$
by the First Isomorphism Theorem. Via the isomorphism above, by the universal property of localization, the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} R @>>> R[x]/\ker\varphi\\ @.     {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{3.52em}{0em}]{}}}} @V\psi VV\\  @. R[x]/(xf-1) \end{CD}
$$
commutes where the arrows are compositions of natural injections and natural projections:
$$
\begin{cases}
 R\hookrightarrow R[x]\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/\ker\varphi
 \\R\hookrightarrow R[x]\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/(xf-1).
\end{cases}
$$
By the universal property of quotient rings, the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} R[x] @>>> R[x]/(xf-1)\\ @.     {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{3.52em}{0em}]{}}}} @VV\phi V\\  @. R[x]/\ker\varphi \end{CD}
$$
commutes where the arrows are compositions of natural projections:
$$
\begin{cases}
 R[x]\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/(xf-1).
 \\R[x]\twoheadrightarrow R[x]/\ker\varphi.
\end{cases}
$$
Now we get two unique homomorphisms $\psi$ and $\phi$ determined by the arrows from $R$ and $R[x]$ to $R[x]/(xf-1)$ and $R[x]/\ker\varphi$.
[1] Whether the isomorphism $(R[x]/(xf-1))/(\ker\varphi/(xf-1))\cong R[x]/\ker\varphi$ is useful or not to solve this problem.
[2] It remains to show that $\ker\pi\subseteq(xf-1)$, which is "not difficult to see that" stated by the authors, but I do not know how to move on. Is there a quick way to show this just by the universal properties of localizations and quotient rings? Since I have not learnt the universal property of polynomial rings as mentioned in other answers.

Update: I have known the usage of the universal property of universal property of localizations, by @linkja and @Bill Dubuque 's help, as follows:
It is clear in the ring $R[x]/\langle xf-1\rangle$ we have that $\iota(1)=1+\langle xf-1\rangle$ and $\iota(f^n)^{-1}=x^n+\langle xf-1\rangle$ where $D=\{\,f^n\,|\,n\geq0\,\}$, so we can use the universal property of localizations to obtain the commutative diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} R @>\sigma>> D^{-1}R\cong R[x]/\ker\varphi\\ @.     {_{\rlap{}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{3.52em}{0em}]{\iota}}}} @V\psi VV\\  @. R[x]/\langle xf-1\rangle \end{CD}
$$
where $\iota=\psi\circ\sigma$. Since $\psi$ is surjective, it suffices to show that $\psi$ is also injective.
In fact, in this commutative diagram, $\psi$ is injective if and only if $\iota$ is injective.
Since $\iota$ is injective proved in this link, $\ker(\psi\circ\sigma)=\ker\iota=0$, i.e., $\forall\,r\in R/\{0\}$, $\psi(r)=\psi(\sigma(r))\ne0$. Since $0\not\in D$, $\forall\,d\in D\subseteq D^{-1}R$, $\psi(d)=\psi\circ\sigma(d)=\iota(d)\in(R[x]/\langle xf-1\rangle)^{\times}$, i.e., $\psi(d)$ is never a zero divisor.
Thus $\forall\,d^{-1}r\in D^{-1}R$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \psi(d^{-1}r)=\psi(d)^{-1}\psi(r)&=0
 \\(\text{since }\psi(d)\text{ is never a zero divisor})\ \ \text{iff}\ \ \psi(r)&=0
 \\\text{iff}\ \ \iota(r)=\psi\circ\sigma(r)=\psi(r)&=0
 \\(\text{since }\iota\text{ is injective})\ \ \text{iff}\ \ r&=0
 \\\text{iff}\ \ d^{-1}r&=0,
\end{aligned}
$$
hence $\psi$ is injective. And since $\psi$ is also a surjective ring homomorphism, $\psi$ is an isomorphism, so finally we get
$$
R_f=D^{-1}R\cong R[x]/\ker\varphi=R[x]/\langle xf-1\rangle,
$$
as desired.

See also answers here. $\ \ $

You want to show that $R[X]/(Xf-1)\cong D^{-1}R$, so you want to construct an isomorphism between them:
For this we work similar as you did in your question:
We look at the obvious morphism $$\pi: R\to R[X] \to R[X]/(Xf-1), r\mapsto r +(Xf-1).$$
i) We see that for all $s\in D = \{f^n:n\geq 0\}$ that $s$ is invertible as its inverse is just $X^n+(Xf-1)$ by the given relation ($Xf = 1$).
ii) And we also see that if $\pi(r) = 0$ in $R[X]/(Xf-1)$ then $r \in (Xf-1)\subset R[X]$, so there is some $P(X) = a_n X^n+...+a_0\in R[X]$ such that $P(X)\cdot(Xf-1) = r$ so we have that $fa_nX^{n+1}+(fa_{n-1}-a_n)X^n+...+ a_0 = r$. comparing coefficients we get that $a_0 = r$ and all other coefficients are equal to zero. Inductively we see that $fa_0-a_1=0$ so $a_1=fa_0 = fr$ and therefore $a_n = f^nr$. At some point $a_n$ is zero and therefore $f^nr = 0$ for some $n$ and we gat that $sr = 0$ for some $s \in D$.
iii) Every element of $R[X]/(Xf-1)$ is of the form $\frac{\pi(r)}{\pi(f^n)}$ as $\frac{1}{\pi(f)} = X$.
By Atiyah-MacDonald Corollary 3.2. in "Intoduction to commutative algabra" $R[X]/(Xf-1)$ is isomorphic to $D^{-1}R$ by the universal property of the localization.
Those are the same calculatinos you did (in part) in your question.
There, as you have written both rings as quotients of the polynomial ring in one variable it is enough to see that the ideals you divide out are the same. The calculation that they are the same ideals is precisely ii). Part iii) was your argument that $R[X]\to D^{-1}R$ is surjective and i) is just in the definition of your map.

The only nontrivial part is the kernel computation (ii) - which was already linked to by my answer linked above (in a comment on the question), namely here where a simple complete proof is given (vs. common handwaving as above). The rest of the above is also a duplicate (follow the links).
